# How do you sign up for Crashlytics?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I want to integrate Crashlytics in an Android app.

I've followed this link and installed the SDK:
http://download.crashlytics.com/android/eclipse/

I've restarted Eclipse and see the Crashlytics icon.

When I click the icon, it asks for user credentials. But I do not currently have an account and am unable to sign up.

It asks for an email address: "Interested? Try Crashlytics".

I've entered my email, but no mail has come to my inbox.

Next it opens the link:
http://try.crashlytics.com/list/?token=Z2FuZXNoQGV2ZW50dXJlcnMuY29tOjo0NzUwMw==&key=dac24708c98fdec25ee3ebe7bce2f386.

How do I register a new Crashlytics account?

Where do I get an API key for Crashlytics?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait 1 or 2 two days.

They will eventually send an invite email to your email address. You will then be able to register and sign in to Crashlytics.

To install the Crashlytics Android SDK, follow the link below:
http://download.crashlytics.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: I haven't got my invitation even after waiting for a month :(

Comment: same here, I didn't get invitation too, even after 2 months.

Answer (score 2):

Crashlytics was acquired by Twitter, and now seems to have been rolled in to their **Fabric** integrated mobile development service.

None of the Crashlytics signup links seem to work any more. They all redirect me to the home page. Very confusing.

You should instead sign up for Fabric:

https://fabric.io/

When I was invited to a Crashlytics account, all I received was the cryptic email below.

I thought this was some weird spam from Twitter that I had forgotten about signing up for. There's no mention of it being related to Crashlytics or to the active invite that I looking for.

However, if you accept the Fabric invite you will receive access to Crashlytics.

[image: Twitter Fabric Crashlytics invite]

Answer (score 0):

Register your details from below link :

[Crashlytics registration](https://www.crashlytics.com/login)

Answer (score 0):

After searching for close to one hour was able to sign up using this link

https://fabric.io/sign_up?signup_campaign_id=https://get.fabric.io